How to run MySQL on a Pi model 3A+?
Based on the output of lscpu, I see my Pi architecture is arm. Based on the output of lsblk, I see my OS version is Raspbian (bullseye).
I attempt to download and run a MySQL version listed under Linux - generic and ARM,64-bit on the MySQL downloads page.
This returns a cannot execute binary file: Exec format error error.
I read online (What is the difference between “Raspbian” Bullseye and “Debian” Bullseye), the ARM architecture used on this model of Pi is specifcally a 32-bit architecture.
There is no 32-bit version of MySQL listed on the MySQL webpage.
Can a 32-bit architecture not run a 64-bit compiled binary ? Are there any 32-bit versions of MySQL available ?
Specifically, I am attempting to run MySQL version 8.3.0, as I am familiar with it. The most helpful answer would be tailored toward attempting to run this version.
Thankyou.

MySQL should probably be available in the package system for your distribution. Be aware that the pi has very slow storage so your database should fit in the RAM you have.

@ThorbjørnRavnAndersen the OP has stated he wants "MySQL version 8.3.0, as I am familiar with it" rather that the very old version in Bullseye.

@Milliways Would prefer… but that’s not important.  I would suggest that using an older version of MySQL readily available might be more useful if it turns out that it is harder than expected to locate and install a suitable binary package.   If Bullseye is as old as you say, now may even be the appropriate time to update to a newer version of the operating system so it has the MySQL package you want.   Used to do that for Ubuntu a lot to get the latest version of Java.

Use MariaDB it's equivalent to MySQL and includes a 32-bit version. I run it on an ancient RPi 1B.

The Pi3A+ has a 64 bit processor, you just have to use a 64 bit Raspberry Pi OS.
Unfortunately while this is an excellent processor the 500MB memory capacity limits what you can achieve and the Desktop performance is mediocre.
I successfully run 64 bit Raspberry Pi OS Bookworm Lite on my 3A+.

I'll chime in & say I agree w/ Milliways. I'll also add FWIW that the 2W doesn't seemto give up much in performance against the 3A+... I've not run any tests, but the 2W typically seems a bit faster than the 3A+.

But the request was for a 32-bit binary package, not a reinstall…

@ThorbjørnRavnAndersen in fact the OP asked for 2 (contradictory) things, 32 bit & v 8.3.0; he can have either. There is no longer any reason NOT to use 64 bit on a compatible Pi as more apps no longer support 32 bit.

@Milliways Can 8.3.0 be built manually on this platform?

Rather than trying to download and build MySQL, you'll find it much easier to use the "package system" (apt) to install software. Before doing this however, you might find your chances of success improve by using a current version of the OS... in the 64-bit version.
"How do I do that?" you might be wondering. You can do this from the CLI:
$ apt-cache search mysql | less
...

You'll find numerous results displayed in your (less) pager. The packages listed will work with your OS & hardware (whatever that is).
Before installing any of the MySQL apps, you should run apt to update & upgrade your system:
$ sudo apt update
...
$ sudo apt -y full-upgrade
...
$ sudo apt install <whatever MySQL package(s) you've decided upon>
...


The OP has stated he wants "MySQL version 8.3.0, as I am familiar with it" rather that the very old version in Bullseye.

@Milliways... he can use backports.

Not if there is no longer 32 bit support.

Yeah - he's screwed on that, but he can always upgrade the OS.

The 32-bit version of raspian is available for download and has had been updated within the last month.

@ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: I guess the question is now: "Can he get MySQL that will run on the 32-bit version of RpiOS?"
